# findViewById working for TextView but NOT for sibling Button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a very weird problem I am having with ViewBinder's setViewValue(View, Cursor, columnIndex). In setViewValue I am trying to access a button in the layout for each item in my listview.

I am able to access and change text of the TextView, but when I try to set the text of the button I get a NullPointerException. The button has an id and I am correctly using the name, the button is also a sibling of textview so if the root view can find the textview, it should be able to find the button.

I tried cleaning the project with no success.

Any other suggestions?

EDIT:
Here is the code for the ViewBinder (setViewValue) and for the layout for each item in the listview:

```
private class CustomViewBinder implements ViewBinder {

    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {

            int upvoted_index=cursor.getColumnIndex("upvote");
            int is_upvoted = cursor.getInt(upvoted_index);
            if (is_upvoted == 1) {

                Button likeButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.voteButton);
                likeButton.setText("Upvoted");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
    }

}
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="20dip"
android:background="@drawable/profile_styling" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:gravity="center" />


<Button
android:id="@+id/voteButton"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="@string/like"
android:background="#00FFFF"
android:paddingTop="20dp"
 />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Taking your layout's structure in consideration, did you tried using the view hierarchy to get to the `Button`? By this I mean using methods like `getParent()` and `getchildAt()` to start from the `TextView` and get to the `Button`.

Comment: The View parameter in setViewValue is the root layout for the view. That is, it is the LinearLayout containing the button and textview. So calling view.findViewById(R.id.button) should be enough. getChildAt() is only for list items, correct?

Comment: Would you please show me your code so that I could point out the error. Because it generally doesn't happen. You have made some minor mistake while initializing your Button.

Comment: Pacemaker has suggested the right solution. Paste here your that block of code in which you are initializing Button.

Comment: *The View parameter in setViewValue is the root layout for the view.* - That's incorrect. The `View` passed to the `setViewValue()` is the view for which a data binding should be done/attempted(its the views with the ids declared in the `to` array passed to the adapter's constructor).

Comment: I think this is the problem @Luksprog . I will try to add a new field for the button in the TO array and see how it goes. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I tried adding the button fields in the to, from arrays but no success still. I have just posted the code.

Comment: @Luksprog I solved it by defining a View superView = view.getParent() , then used superView.findViewById to get the button and it worked. Post this as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
ViewGroup superView = (ViewGroup)view.getParent();
Button btn = (Button) superView.findViewById(R.id.votewButton);
```

Also using the array of view ids that you pass to the adapter's constructor would be a good alternative:

```
String[] from = {/*any collumns that you may have*/, "_id"}; // just bind a column, we don't use it
int[] = {/*any collumns that you may have*/, R.id.voteButton};
```

The in the `ViewBinder` you'll have:

```
@Override
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
    // only if we're binding the Button
    if (view.getId == R.id.voteButton) {
        int upvoted_index=cursor.getColumnIndex("upvote");
        int is_upvoted = cursor.getInt(upvoted_index);
        if (is_upvoted == 1) {
            Button likeButton = (Button) view;
            likeButton.setText("Upvoted");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: getParent() returns ViewParent not View

Comment: @Superbiji How is that not working? Do you have the exact same scenario? What exactly are you trying to do?